# Bootstrap removes body color?

Tags: html

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #c9ffd6;
}
.wrapper{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 93%;
  background-color: #a4f4b8;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <title>Felpix | Home</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta name="description" content="Welcome to Felpix Studios, a brand new tech startup making simple, yet helpful apps!">
   <meta name="keywords" content="Felpix, iOS, Android, apps, games, code">
   <meta name="author" content="Felpix">
   <!--Libraries-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
 </head>
  <body>
    <div class="w3-animate-zoom wrapper"> <!--Page and Animation-->
      <header>
        <div>
          <h1>Felpix Studios</h1>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div> <!--Header-->
      </header>
    </div> <!--End of Page-->
 </body>
 </html>
```

So I add the bootstrap  tag so I can use it in my website. Along with it, I also have the w3css libraries too. And when I open my website, the body's color went from a light green to white... Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `wrapper` class that has a height of `100vh`, so it will occupy the entire screen. Simply take out `background-color` in the wrapper class:

```
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #c9ffd6;
}
.wrapper{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 93%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Or change it to the same colour as `body`:

```
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #c9ffd6;
}
.wrapper{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 93%;
  background-color: #c9ffd6;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```

You could also specify that the body's background is `!important`, to give it more specificity than `.wrapper`:

```
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #c9ffd6 !important;
}
```

A fourth option would be to set a `z-index` greater than 0 on the body, so that it appears 'in front' of the wrapper:

```
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #c9ffd6;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, sorry, but I was looking for a way to keep the colors that I put... If you could help with that, much thanks! 

Comment: ...so you want a `wrapper` that occupies 100% of the height of the page, and has a background colour... but you don't want that colour to be visible at all, and don't want to remove the code that creates that colour? What's the point of even having the colour then? It *is* possible to use a `z-index` to have the body show up above the wrapper, though it's incredibly poor practice  -- I'll update my answer to showcase that.